# Kotlin flow like ordered broadcast receiver in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking for something in Koltin coroutines like the `sendOrderedBroadcast` in Android. The broadcast receiver with order and priority could abort the broadcast to prevent subsequent receivers with lower priority receiving it.

I want to use Koltin `Flow` or `Channel` instead of Android's `BroadcastReceiver` since the business are irrelevant with android context. Is there any `Flow` or `Channel` already implemented functionality like that in coroutines? Or I just need to implement it by myself.

Comment: The definition of what you need it to do is very broad. You can do most of that logic with flows but it's not clear where/how you need to use it.

Comment: @TheLibrarian The key point is `sendOrderedBroadcast` and `abortBroadcast` functionality. Normal flow can't support that behavior.